# ASP.NET 4.0 Session Fixation Exploits

Tags: asp.net, security

Does ASP.NET 4.0 have any improvements as to inbuilt protection against [Session Fixation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation) attacks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it dosn't............................